# Kubernetes cluster hangs when pod consumes too much memory

Tags: kubernetes, memory

I have a job I run on a k8s node that quickly grows to 32Gb+ memory. The node has 32Gb of memory.

I would expect Kubernetes to evict the pod, but instead the node becomes completely unreachable and the only way to get it back is with a reboot. Looking at htop immediately after deploying the job, all CPUs and memory are maxed out.

Even when I set memory limits on the job configuration to 16M, the same happens.

This is what the job config looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: mem-test
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mem-test
        image: gcr.io/foo/mem-test:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 16000Mi
      restartPolicy: Never
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show your yaml manifests.

Comment: @Thomas Updated the question with the job yaml.

Comment: Is that an application that produces high memory load or is it just checking the allocation? What kind of node are you using?

Comment: @Thomas this is the app that produces the load. This is a bare-metal OVH instance running ubuntu 18

Comment: Do you have swap memory enabled? To get it more stable I would add CPU limits and diagnose it from there. You can also try a newer ubuntu LTS, f.e. 20.04 which has a more recent kernel.

Comment: @Thomas It turns out updating the kernel solved the issue... thanks for your help!